# sound.play is not a function (it is undefined)

Tags: react-native, expo

I am developing a mobile app on Expo using React Native. Below I am trying to have the user use a slider to adjust the frequency played through their phone. I have imported all of the necessary libraries (including @react-native-community/audio-toolkit) and keep getting this one error. I know I am not defining specifically what sound.play() is, but I assumed that the play function should have already been established through the API. Can someone please explain to me what is happening here and how I can fix it? Thanks in advance.

```
  const [frequency, setFrequency] = useState(20);
  const [freq, setFreq] = useState(20);
  const [sound, setSound] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const generator = new AudioGenerator({ sampleRate: 44100 });
    const newSound = generator.generate((time) => {
      return Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * frequency * time);
    });

  setSound(newSound);

  return () => {
    if (newSound) {
      newSound.stop();
    }
  };
}, [frequency]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (sound) {
      sound.play(sound).catch(error => console.error('Error playing sound:', error));;
    }

  return () => {
    if (sound) {
      sound.stop();
    }
  };
}, [sound]);

      const onSliderValueChange = (value) => {
        const freq = Math.ceil(value);
        setFrequency(freq);
        setFreq(freq);
      };

      sound.play(sound);

      setTimeout(() => {
        sound.stop();
      }, duration * 1000);

      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Slider
            minimumTrackTintColor="pink"
            minimumValue={20}
            maximumValue={20000}
            onValueChange={onSliderValueChange}
          />
          <Text style={styles.texttt}>{freq} HZ</Text>

        </View>
      );
```

So far, I have tried adjusting the useEffects so the logic and structure of the code was more defined. This did not help me, so I think there is either a problem with how I am declaring the function or the API itself is not suitable for what I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

can you show where setSound is used, sound is here an empty array, not a function to call you can use it like

```
let sound = new Player(String path, Object ?playbackOptions)
```